# Is the PyThreadState* of the main python thread expected to be NULL?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, gil

I have a python program that calls into a c++ library, which wishes to release all the python locks so that other python threads can run.

Using `PyEval_SaveThread` and `PyEval_ReleaseThread` I get errors that the thread state is NULL:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate
```

However, the lower-level function seem to accept the NULL state happily:

```
PyThreadState *s;
s = PyThreadState_Swap(NULL);
// (now s = 0)
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// ....

PyEval_AcquireLock();
PyThreadState_Swap(s);

// everything seems to be just fine :)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: **no**, it is never meant to be `NULL` (if it is, it's a fatal error). Turned out this was because I was linking against two different versions of python, one via boost_python, and the other directly.

Top Tip:
use `ldd` or `otool -L` to check your library dependencies when funny stuff happens ;)